# How can i detect the silence in the asterisk dial plan while recording user voices?

Tags: php, asterisk, telephony

How can i detect the silence in the asterisk dial plan while recording user voices?

Step1: My code for recording firstname as

```
exten => s,n,wait(1)
exten => s,n(getfirstname),Playback(var/lib/asterisk/sounds/mysoundfiles/getfirstname)
exten => s,n,Record(var/lib/asterisk/sounds/mysoundfiles/firstname:wav,0,10)
exten => s,n,Hangup
```

Step2: My requirement is to hangup the call after 5 sec If silence..

Answer (score 0):

As per your Dial-Plan state your recording will stop if 10 seconds sileance received when recording is going on . so isuggest please replcae line

Record(var/lib/asterisk/sounds/mysoundfiles/firstname:wav,0,5) and your solutions is ready.

Comment: Ya i know that the 3rd parameter of Record() application is used to set maximum time to record, But I need to hang up the call after 5 seconds silence while recording even the maximum time has set..Is there any idea for silence detection?

Answer (score 0):

```
core show application Record 
--snip--    
[Syntax]
Record(filename.format[,silence[,maxduration[,options]]])
```

So,

```
Record(var/lib/asterisk/sounds/mysoundfiles/firstname.wav,5,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Silence is not flat 0000000's . That silence option is mostly no signal. In normal recording situations, if the user does not say anything, some noise is still recorded and the recording does not stop.

Comment: In that case, is there any standard way to distinguish between near-silence noise and regular speaking?